# AJAX Toolkit cascading dropdown list database - CS ok, but VB fail

Tags: asp.net, database, drop-down-menu, cascading

Cascading dropdown list is ok with CS but the same site in VB doesn't work. In VB the last dropdown list looses it's value when postback, it takes the value of the previous dropdown list.

The two sites are in the following link [sites](http://sdrv.ms/RYm7AK).

Both sites have the the same version of the database.

I really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: why are you doing the same site in both vb and c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line # 92 of the `Webservice.vb` :

```
CiudadLista.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue(CiudadNombre, MunicipioID))
```